# DOMDocument need to search for an element that has attribute class="something"

Tags: php, domdocument

In PHP I'm using DOMDocument and I need to search for an element that has attribute class="something"

I'm new with DOMDocument (been using REGEX all my life so help me :P)

Ok, my question is, I've found a DOMElement using getElementById, now i want to look inside the children of this element and retrieve a node that has a particular class, class="something"

How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a `DOMNode` `$n` for a document `$d` whose children you want to filter by class you can do (this searches recursively):

```
$xp = new DOMXpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query('//*[contains(@class, \'classname\')]', $n) as $found) {
    //do sth with $found
}
```

The point of `contains` is to catch those nodes whose class attribute has more than one value, but it's a bit too coarse. See [here](http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/0036_xpath_to_select_html_by_class.html) for a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain `$n` ? is it tagname? Like `div` `section` etc?

Comment: @Sisir It's an object of type `DOMNode` (in particular a `DOMElement`). In the OP's case, he's getting it with `DOMDocument::getElementById()`. It will represent an element in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) query:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
// keep the quotes around the classname
$elementsThatHaveMyClass = $xpath->query('//*[@class="class here"]');
```

The expression means "from anywhere in the document, find any tag whose `class` attribute is equal to `class here`". You can read more on the XPath syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp).