# target html class and fill with content DOMdocument

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I am aiming to fill an html element of a certain std html class with content

This answer has a pretty complex concat xpath query:
[Using DOMDocument to extract from HTML document by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121833/using-domdocument-to-extract-from-html-document-by-class#answer-5121899)

This class extension will get and fill html nicely:
https://gist.github.com/j0shua/945507

This is the example html i am working with:

```
        <!-- actual content of the page box -->
    <div class="masterWidthSet mainContent">
        <div class="mainPageContent">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/email_js.js"></script>

            <b>Contact us all at the same time...</b><br/>
            <div class="messageSent">Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.</div>
            <table class="contactForm">
                <tr><td class="title">Name</td><td class="description"><input type="text" id="sendName" class="text" placeholder="Your name..."></td></tr>

                <tr><td class="title">Number (optional)</td><td class="description"><input type="text" id="phoneNo" class="text"placeholder="Your number..."></td></tr>

                <tr><td class="title">Email</td><td class="description"><input type="text" id="email" class="text"placeholder="Your email..."></td></tr>

                <tr><td class="title">Message</td><td class="description"><textarea id="message" class="text"placeholder="Your message..."></textarea></td></tr>

                <tr><td></td><td class="description"><input type="button" class="submit" value="Send us you message..." onclick="sendMessage()"/><span class="description messageStatus" id="messageStatus"></span></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can easily get the innHTML of the element with a single class '**mainPageContent**':

```
require_once WEBROOT_PRIVATE.'scripts/JSLikeHTMLElement.php';
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'JSLikeHTMLElement');
$dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $file['local_path'] ) );
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$elem = $xpath->query('//*[@class="mainPageContent"]')->item(0);
echo $elem->innerHTML;
```

But as soon as i try to target a element with multiple classes it returns null (i am assuming because the query is looking for a an exact match) eg '**mainContent**':

```
$elem = $xpath->query('//*[@class="mainContent"]')->item(0);
```

So I tried to use the concat query from the top post but i get 'Call to a member function item()':

```
$elem = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' mainContent ')")->item(0);
```

So i tried this:

```
$elem = $xpath->query('//*[class~="mainContent"]')->item(0);
```

The problem is each time the item(0) results in an error:

> Call to a member function item() on a non-object

This guy says the ways i tried should work.. [Selecting a css class with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath#answer-9133579)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrap all of the above and just use the phpquery library.

Just like jquery for php! bish bash bosh.

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/