# PHP regex match by class name multiple elements

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following HTML with many classes:

```
<img class="lorem ipsum red" />
<img class="red" />
<img class="lorem red ipsum dolor" />
<img class="red ipsum" />
```

I'm using `preg_match_all` to find all images

`preg_match_all( '/<img [^>]+>/', $html, $matches )`

Is it possible to match all `img` tags which have class name `red`?

I tried `/red\d+/` but does not work

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651303/regex-match-img-tag-with-certain-attribute-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Using regex to find HTML elements (of this complexity): Bad idea. Use**
>   **an HTML parser and XPath! Even in JavaScript you can leverage DOM.**

```
?php 
$doc =<<<DEMO
<img class="lorem ipsum red" />
<img class="red" />
<img class="lorem red ipsum dolor" />
<img class="red ipsum" />
DEMO;

$xml = new DOMDocument();
//Or you could use for locally saved files
//@$xml->loadHTMLFile('savedfile.html');
@$xml->loadHTML($doc);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
    if(strstr($image->getAttribute('class'),'red')==true){
        $images[] = $image->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
print_r($images);
?>
```

Here is [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651668/6556397).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:

```
/<img.+?class=".*?red.*?"/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vLbXIJ/1